# Heroku Data for Redis difference with Redit Enterprise Cloud

Tags: heroku, redis

I want to use redis for caching, and I see that besides the service provided by Heroku there's also an add-on from Redis Cloud, which is cheaper.
What's the difference? Will they both have the same performance?